# How to use OpenStreetMap data on Rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS.
I want to use data provided by OpenStreetMap and visualize using Rviz.
The data is in .osm format.

please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279647/how-to-use-openstreetmap-data-on-rviz?/) by [pallyra1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33259/pallyra1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if #q276809 provides some clues.

Possibly [osm_cartography](http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography) could be of use.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallyra1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33259/pallyra1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Okay.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the `osm_cartography` package (http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography?distro=kinetic) which might help you.
It transforms OSM data like roads etc. and publishes this as markers.

Maybe try Google next time. This leads you directly to this package.
If you then have more questions, you can still come asking questions here.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallyra1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33259/pallyra1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Okay.
Will try it.
Thank you so much.